# Creating half a number pyramid in PHP with for loops

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, numbers

I was told to create half a pyramid in for loops using php that looks as follows:

54321
4321
321
21
1
This is what I had created so far but I have no idea how to go about creating the rest of the pyramid.

```
for ($iB = 5; $iB >=0; $iB--) {  
   echo $iB.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: you would need to use double for loop

Comment: Save the upper limit in a variable. After each complete run of the loop decrease it by one. Wrap the loop into another loop.

Comment: will the input always be `54321`? Seems rather useless exercise without making it work for any input

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested `for loop`. Try this...

```
for ($iB = 5; $iB > 0; $iB--) {
    for($i = $iB; $i > 0; $i--){
        echo $i;
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, my main issue lied with not knowing that I could assign the second value($i) to be equal to that of the first($iB)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone decides not to use numbers for input, do

```
$str = '54321';
while( $str ) {
    echo $str . PHP_EOL; // use <br> if output is in html
    $str = substr( $str, 1 );
}
```