# How to make this Number Pyramid Pattern

Tags: php, algorithm, for-loop

is it possible if I want an output like this?

```
5 4 3 2 1
  4 3 2
    3
```

with PHP, this is the code that I've been trying:

```
$n = 3;
for ($i = 3; $i > 0; $i--) {
    for ($j = $n - $i; $j > 0; $j--)
        echo "  ";
    for ($j = 2 * $i - 1; $j > 0 ; $j--)
        echo " ".$j;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

and I got this, from that code:

```
5 4 3 2 1
  3 2 1
    1
```

Which part of my code did I get wrong? Can someone help me?

**EDIT:** Thanks people. most of the stackoverflow question that similar to my question is like my result that I have. the task was not that. 54321 432 3
most of them we're like 54321 4321 321 21 1. I'm sorry , I'm newbie. don't know as much as you people. once again, Thanks a lot!

Comment: is the variable just $n?

Comment: There's $i and $j

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating half a number pyramid in PHP with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851836/creating-half-a-number-pyramid-in-php-with-for-loops)

Comment: @PJTraill read..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your last for loop's initial value and condition to match your criteria:

```
$n = 3;
for ($i = 3; $i > 0; $i--) {
    for ($j = $n - $i; $j > 0; $j--)
        echo "  ";
    for ($j = $n + $i - 1; $j > $n - $i ; $j--)
        echo " ".$j;
    echo "<br>";
}
```